# Three things you should listen to your wife?

Tags: sources-mekorot, women, marriage, trust-neemanut

What are the three items in which one must listen to his wife (because it's divinely inspired)? I forget what they are but I heard them in a shiur. I think it's sourced in the gemarah.

Something like where to live, business and a third item?

Comment: This reminds me of the line you hear in some Jewish schools: "In our culture, every day is Mother's Day and Father's Day."

Comment: isn't it the opposite? - 3 things you should not listen

Comment: I'm surmising that one of them is regarding when someone is a bad influence on your child. Per Sarah's advice to Abraham to chase out Hagar and Ishmael, to which G-d says, listen to Sarah.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat similar is in Gemara Berachot: The wife knows to diagnose

> ‏{‏  מלכים ב ד-ט ‏}‏ ותאמר אל אישה הנה נא ידעתי כי איש אלהים קדוש הוא א''ר יוסי בר' חנינא מכאן שהאשה מכרת באורחין יותר מן האיש.‏
>
> And she said unto her husband: Behold now, I perceive that he is a holy man of God.

Rabbi Jose Berabbi Hanina said: You learn from this that a woman recognizes the character of a guest better than a man.'

Answer (score 0):

another source [Baba Mezi'a 59a](http://halakhah.com/babamezia/babamezia_59.html)

from which you can understand that 2 things might be regarding household affairs and/or secular questions

> Rab also said: He who follows his wife's counsel will descend ***14***  into Gehenna, for it is written, But there was none like unto Ahab [which did sell himself to work wickedness in the sight of the Lord, whom Jezebel his wife stirred up].***15***  R. papa objected to Abaye: But people say, **If your wife is short, bend down and hear her whisper**! — There is no difficulty: the one refers to general matters; the other to **household affairs**.***16***  Another version: the one refers to religious matters, the other to **secular questions.**
>    14 Lit., 'fall'.
>    15 I Kings, XXI, 25; thus Ahab's downfall is ascribed to his action in allowing himself to be led astray by Jezebel.
>    16 A man should certainly consult his wife on the latter, but not on the former, — not a disparagement of woman; her activities lying mainly in the home.